# Link Two taskflows Oracle Adf libraries

Tags: oracle-adf, adf-task-flow

I am learning to create an ADF enterprise application. I have separated my apps in jar modules as described by Sten E. Vesterli in Developing Web application with ADF. I have two jars that contain two taskflows. How do I link the two in my main app so that after login the button takes me to the DashTaskFlow?

LoginApp has an AuthTaskflow and Dashboard has a DashTaskflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a containing taskflow - either bounded or unbounded (depending on how you want to enter/invoke it) and drag/drop the two JAR'd taskflows into the containing taskflow, then have one TF call/navigate to the other. Since the JAR'd TFs are bounded TFs, when one calls the other the called TF default activity will be invoked automatically on entry.

Comment: I have done that but my login button cannot find the other task flow since its not instantiated inside it.

Comment: So, Page 1 contains the button and is inside the containing taskflow - and there is a navigation from that that page to the first desired taskflow and the button is coded to call this flow case - and it does not work? You need a navigation flow case from the page containing the button to the desired (jar'd) task flow call.